# gnuplot: Plot file with linespoints but with fewer points

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to `plot` a file with `linespoints` in `Gnuplot` but the line using all the data samples and the points using fewer data samples. For example the following file plots the data but the line is not visible at all.

```
set terminal png
set out "plot_sample.png"
plot [t=-1000:1000] t w linespoints pt 64 lt 10 ps 1.5
```

How to do it if I want to define a custom sampling interval for the points but use all the data samples for the line? I could do two separate plots in the same figure but then the key will show both of them separately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pointinterval` to reduce the number of plotted points, but keep all points for drawing the line:

```
set samples 100
plot x**2 w linespoints pointinterval 10
```

Comment: you've beaten me m(_ _)m

Comment: @gnzlbg `pointinterval` is an option specific to `linespoints`. To plot only every tenth point, use `plot ... every 10 with points`

Comment: But the `every` command only works for data points, right? What if you want to plot a function with points and control the point density?

Comment: @Martin That's what ``set samples` does

Answer (score 2):

- Use `every` to reduce the samples taken from file!
- Plot the line and
  the points in two part, and use `notitle` at one of them!
- Don't forget to 'synchronize' the color of the 2 plots!

Something like:

```
plot [t=-1000:1000] 'data.dat' w l lt 10 lc 10 t 'something', '' every 10 w p pt 64 ps 1.5 lc 10 notitle
```

---

**NOTES**

Usage of `every`: plot 'alma.dat' every A:B:C:D:E:F

where

- A is the data increment (every Ath)
- B is the datablock increment (datablocks are separated by empty lines)
- C/D is the first data/datablock (start from C/D)
- E/F is the last data/datablock (end at E/F)

You can use all the features described above, but if you don't need, just leave it empty, eg. ...every 2 or every 2::1 or every 2::1:0 ect...